# Is there any way to load individual data and display it rather loading and display all data using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Consider I have 10 locations and I have to display each location's weather conditions. It is easy to fetch all locationids and feed it to a function to get all 10 location's data at a time and display it. But I want to load individually  from server side and feed it to angular section. ie when first location data loaded then display it then second and so on.. Is that possible?

This is my angular code. This working fine. I want to change to above mentioned logic

```
var locations = [1,2,3,...,10];
locationService.UpdateDashBoard(locations).then(function (result) {
    $scope.results.push(result.data);  
});
```

And Html code is

```
<li gridster-item="widget" ng-repeat="widget in results">
   <div class="text-center wrap-text">
       <span ng-show="!editMode">{{ widget.name }}</span>
       <label style="cursor: move" ng-show="editMode">{{ widget.name }}</label>
       <div class="pull-right" ng-show="editMode && widget.Source">
           Location - {{widget.location}}
           temperature - {{widget.Source.temperature}}
       </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: You can use ng-animate or $timeout for the above requirement though it loads everything but it wil load with a delay

Comment: If $timeout used, what happen if network become slow?

Comment: How'd it go @SHADOWS? Was the suggestion helpful in any way?

Answer (score 0):

While your `locationService.UpdateDashBoard` function may accept multiple ids, as you stated in your question, passing a list of ids will result in all data being returned at once. Given your requirement to load each location individually, you could simply call the service once for each id:

```
var locations = [1,2,3,...,10];    
locations.forEach(function(location) {  
    locationService.UpdateDashBoard([location]).then(function (result) {
        $scope.results.push(result.data);
    });
});
```

After each call responds the location's data is pushed in the `$scope.results` array. This is where angular's magic kicks in...as you have bound the `ng-repeat` directive to your results array - the UI will automatically update after each new location is added.

Comment: I took it from your question that data for each location is loaded separately: "when first location data loaded". If that's the case, and UpdateDashBoard is just calling some remote resource multiple times, then any difference in performance would be negligible.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation would [greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you want to get all data in one hit (results) but add them to the DOM incrementally. I'm not sure MS_AU's answer will provide the right functionality you need - it looks like it will call the server for every id, but pass the entire array and returns all data from the server every time. You'd end up with 100 items in `$scope.results`.

**Edit:** If my understanding of your question is correct you want to call the server for each id, so you should change your service method to accept one id, and iterate over the ids and call the function.

If you return the promise in a private function you can call `.then()` inside the forEach loop and push the result. If you don't return the $promise in the service function, you'll need to handle the `.$promise` in the controller.

```js
var locations = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var updateDashboard = function(id) {
    return locationService.UpdateDashBoard(id);
};
locations.forEach(function(id) {
    updateDashboard(id).then(function (result) {
        $scope.results.push(result.data);
    });
});
```

And your HTML:

```html
<li gridster-item="widget" ng-repeat="widget in results">
  <!-- fade is just an ng-animate class I picked, you can choose your own or none -->
  <div class="text-center wrap-text fade">
     <span ng-show="!editMode">{{ widget.name }}</span>
     <label style="cursor: move" ng-show="editMode">{{ widget.name }}</label>
     <div class="pull-right" ng-show="editMode && widget.Source">
         Location - {{widget.location}}
         temperature - {{widget.Source.temperature}}
     </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this logic is same as I mentioned except forloop with timeout is used. I want to load individually from server side and feed it to angular section.

Comment: I've updated my answer to what I understand your requirement to be

Comment: Thank you for the update. What I want is when a user load the dashboard, user should feel that a background process is in progress.So I want that loaded data should display and pending data later. So that user can't get bored. I will check this code surely :)

Comment: I think you could probably expand upon this with a better UI and provide a loading indicator of sorts beneath the ng-repeat with `ng-if="results.length == locations.length"` and add `locations` to your `$scope`

Comment: my bad! - had a typo in my answer. Looks like you went with the same approach. Out of curiosity - why the added complexity of the private function? What value is it adding?

Comment: I suppose it comes down to syntactic sugar and preference. I would usually have a private function that I call from functions on the Scope, especially if it's reusable. I like to keep the Scope as clean as possible, but it can be achieved without the private function.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like that you wanted to do a sequencing request by chaining each of the id one after another. I would recommend to use [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) to do that.

```
var locations = [1,2,3,...,10];

// create a "start" promise
var promiseChain = $q.when(function(){});

// loop each locations
locations.forEach(function (location) {

    // promisify the locationService function
    var promiselink = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        locationService.UpdateDashBoard([location])
        .then(function (result) {
            $scope.results.push(result.data); 
            deferred.resolve() 
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }

    // promiseChain will wait until promiselink return with the promise
    promiseChain = promiseChain.then(promiselink);
})
```

The `promiseChain.then(promiselink);` should do the trick since it waits for promise to be resolved from promiselink function.